# C++ namespaces type name is not allowed

Tags: vector, stl, namespaces

I have a problem with C++ namespaces

I want to have a vector shortcut for iterator of some framework.
This works totally fine.

```
using namespace std;
using namespace GS;

typedef vector<vector<String> >::const_iterator table_iter;
```

However, this yields "Error: type name now allowed."

```
//using namespace std;
using namespace GS;

typedef vector<vector<String> >::const_iterator table_iter;
```

The `String` is actually a `GS::String` and I don't want to use `using namespace xxx` in my header file. So I thought this should work

```
//using namespace std;
//using namespace GS;

typedef vector<vector<GS::String> >::const_iterator table_iter;
```

Which also yields "Error: type name now allowed."

Obviously, I can do

```
using namespace std;
//using namespace GS;

typedef vector<vector<GS::String> >::const_iterator table_iter;
```

But why do I need the `std`? I think that namespace `GS` has some macros about using std.

Is there any way to do something like this?

```
typedef vector<vector<GS(YeahImUsingStd)::String> >::const_iterator table_iter;
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I cannot edit the GS namespace!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vector` is in namespace `std`, so you need prefix `std::` before:

```
using namespace GS;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<String> >::const_iterator table_iter;
```

or, to avoid using namespace `GS` too:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<GS::String> >::const_iterator table_iter;
```

But, because you only need `vector` from the standard library, you can do that too:

```
using std::vector;
using namespace GS;
typedef vector<vector<String> >::const_iterator table_iter;
```

In this way you says to the compiler you want to use `vector` from `std::` namespace, but not bring all namespace.

But you said you want to avoid `using namespace` in your header file. That is usually good idea (including `using std::vector`), so the best solution is the second one:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<GS::String> >::const_iterator table_iter;
```

Comment: Omg. I feel like an idiot now. Maybe I should go to bed for a while. Anyway thanks! It is so obvious, but my IDE showed me something different, so I totally forgot about the std::vector.